Flutter 3.24.3 problem with Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1
When I update Android studio to last version "Ladybug 2024.2.1" an error occur whenever I run application in android emulator or physical phone, this problem shows an error with a specific library but in fact it occur with all libraries, I know that because every library tell me there is an error with, I just try to remove it then try running the code again.
This is the error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':google_sign_in_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':google_sign_in_android:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/zaydahmad/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar.
Error while executing process /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /Users/zaydahmad/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/fd4e2b69c2691a24d99d2b3c10c60f94/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /Users/zaydahmad/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/fd4e2b69c2691a24d99d2b3c10c60f94/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 9s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I have update all the libraries to the last version.
I have remove every library appear with that error, it doesn't work.
maybe these files help you solve the problem:
android/app/build.gradle
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip

android/build.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


The issue comes from Android Studio Ladybug having bundled a version of Java that isn't fully backward compatible with Flutter's plugin ecosystem. The solution is to separately install a version of Java (such as Java 17) and configure your project to use it.

Install Java SDK 17 using your method of choice* (either manually or using a runtime manager such as asdf).

Run this command pointing at the location where you installed Java SDK 17:
flutter config --jdk-dir <path-to-java-sdk-17-home-directory>


(Optional, but some plugins may require it) Open android/app/build.gradle and update your Java compatibility options:
android {
    compileOptions {
      sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
      targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    // If using Kotlin
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
}




Further reading:

How to fix Android Compilation issues in Android Studio Ladybug.
Android build warnings about Java with latest Gradle: source value 8 is obsolete/target value 8 is obsolete
Flutter Android Gradle Migration Guide
Gradle-Toolchain-Java Compatibility Matrix


*: If you install the JDK via Homebrew, you may need to update your PATH and/or JAVA_HOME as laid out in @prensj's answer.

Does it works if I downgrade Android studio to the version before "Ladybug"?

@HarithBashar Downgrading Android Studio should also help, but ultimately the problem isn't Android Studio itself but the version of the JDK that comes bundled with it.

if you use brew install openjdk@17 to install jdk, you need to set java_home with this commands:
sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.jdk
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
and after:
flutter config --jdk-dir /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17

Thanks to Sergio's comment above:

if you use brew install openjdk@17 to install jdk, you need to set java_home with this commands: sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.jdk echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc and after: flutter config --jdk-dir /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17

I personally had this issue arise when I upgraded from Android Studio Jellyfish to LadyBug.
I believe the issue stems from the Android Studio default JAVA runtime not being backwards compatible with some flutter plugins / gradio.
My solution was to change the Java runtime to 17, as it is compatible with the version of gradio I am using.
The problem I then faced was trying to set JAVA_HOME.
I had installed Java 17 with brew and Android Studio did not like the PATH.
The Solution:
Install Java 17 via brew

brew install openjdk@17

Create a symbolic link for the Java 17

sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.jdk

Add path to the symbolic link (I am using zsh, change to ~/.bashrc if you use bash)

echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

Configure Flutter to use the install Java 17

flutter config --jdk-dir /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17

Restart Terminal and Android Studio

Run you AVD

flutter run



Thank you for this solution, It's worked for me finally :)

When this bug is fixed, what we have to do to remove this solution from the system? delete java17 from brew? and remove the symbolic link? Everything has to be undone? Or the new version of Android Studio will override it?

/opt/homebrew does not exists in my machine, it does not work
instead brew installs it in /usr/local/Cellar/??? Is that correct?

Cause I am having this error in Android Studio:
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@17

Below is the complete steps for updating a Flutter Android app to support the latest Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) with all necessary changes.
android/app/build.gradle
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

android {
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = "27.0.12077973"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutter.versionCode
        versionName = flutter.versionName
    }
}

android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.9-all.zip

android/build.gradle
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        if (it.hasProperty('android')) {
            it.android.compileSdkVersion = 35
            it.android.defaultConfig.targetSdkVersion = 35
            it.android.compileOptions.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
            it.android.compileOptions.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
            tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
                kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
            }
            if (it.android.namespace == null) {
                def manifest = new XmlSlurper().parse(file(it.android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile))
                def packageName = manifest.@package.text()
                android.namespace = packageName
                println("Updating namespace ${packageName}")
            }
        }
    }
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}

android/settings.gradle
includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

repositories {
    google {
        content {
            includeGroupByRegex("com\\.android.*")
            includeGroupByRegex("com\\.google.*")
            includeGroupByRegex("androidx.*")
        }
    }
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.7.1" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.20" apply false
}

Details
These changes update your Flutter Android project to be compatible with the latest AGP version, by specifying new plugin versions, aligning SDK levels, managing Java compatibility, and correctly configuring the build logic to align with the updates. Make sure to test your app thoroughly after making these changes to ensure stability and compatibility.

My changes helps me to resolve this problem to use java 21 in my Flutter project:
android\settings.gradle
    plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.7.1" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.24" apply false

}

android/app/build.gradle
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.10.2-all.zip

android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_21
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_21
    }

is all changes after upgrade from koala to ladybug.
if needed , do not forgot update flutter plugins to last version i.e. device_info_plus: ^11.1.0
if u get warnings about NDK ...
Your project is configured with Android NDK 23.1.7779620, but the following plugin(s) depend on a different Android NDK version:
- connectivity_plus requires Android NDK 27.0.12077973

Fix this issue by using the highest Android NDK version (they are backward compatible).
Add the following to  ......android\app\build.gradle:

    android {
        ndkVersion = "27.0.12077973"
        ...
    }

u can add this line or u comment this line like me
// ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

then i use current NDK :-)
