Can't launch a flutter application in android emulator
I am working on a Windows 11 laptop. Through visual code editor, I created a new flutter application from scratch (I pressed Ctrl + Shift + P and chose  "Flutter: New Project" command). The project was created successfully. The "flutter run" command is running without any errors when I attach the debug process to a web browser. However, when I try to attach it to an Android emulator (which is already running) I get an error in terminal(The android emulators I use are created with Android studio). I also get the same error when I try to set an android emulator as a build target through Android studio (latest version).
The error I get is the following in all cases.
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform:  %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path  %USERPROFILE%\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output  %USERPROFILE%\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I have tried to solve (unsuccessfully) this problem by following the suggestions I found in these posts:

Gradle failure when building Flutter app: Error while executing JdkImageTransform in Android Studio: Could not resolve all files for configuration
Flutter App stuck at "Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... "

I have also tried to run this command which was included in the previous error message:
./jlink.exe --module-path %USERPROFILE%\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output %USERPROFILE%\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules

but it returns this message (can't figure out what it means):
Error: jdk.tools.jlink.plugin.PluginException: ModuleTarget is malformed: platformString missing delimiter: android

I have also followed these docs to install dart and flutter:

https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows/mobile
https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/android/install-android/install-android-from-web-on-windows

Is there any solution to this problem? It would be really helpful to be able to debug my app inside an Android emulator.

Did you already try to downgrade your JDK to JDK 17?  Its mentioned in the comment of accepted answer. "also had to go back to JDK 17 (from JDK 21) and update the gradle package to version 8.3. Then everything worked fine"

and can you provide us your java and gradle version?

I use the embedded java of the Android studio. When I installed android studio in my laptop, this version of java was also installed: "openjdk version "21.0.3" 2024-04-16". That's why, I installed this version "openjdk version "17.0.12" 2024-07-16". I did it from within the UI of android studio. I have also set a system variable called JAVA_HOME to the path where the version 17.0.12 was found. About gradle, I use the one that is included inside the android folder of the flutter project, which is version 8.3.

Also, after running "gradlew --version" in terminal (while being in the android folder of my flutter project), I also get these information: Kotlin: 1.9.0, Groovy: 3.0.17, Ant:Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13, JVM: 17.0.12

I just found this post which solved my case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79067849/flutter-3-24-3-problem-with-android-studio-ladybug-2024-2-1?rq=1

The issue appears to be related to the version and/or configuration of Java in use. Ensure Java 11 is installed and configure JAVA_HOME to point to its location. To use an embedded JDK with Android Studio, it can be changed under File > Project Structure > SDK Location. Try cleaning Gradle by running flutter clean, and deleting the .gradle folder. The gradle-wrapper.properties can be replaced with a compatible gradle version by uncommenting and altering the line below. Do a fresh install of Android SDK Platform 34 using Android Studio and recreate the Android emulator if necessary. This should fix it.

As I mentioned in another comment, under my initial post, I used the embedded java which was installed with android studio. At first, I used the jdk 21 and then I also Installed jdk 17 through File > Project Structure > SDK Location. I have also added JAVA_HOME for jdk 17 into the system variables. To be honest, I haven't tried to install jdk 11 yet. I'll give it a try later, and return to you with a feedback.
